# For what values of $x$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4}}-\frac{x}{n+2}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4}}-\frac{x}{n+2}$$

So $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4}}-\frac{x}{n+2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+4}}-\frac{x}{(n+1)+2}$. I know that for a series to be convergent, the condition that $$\left|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$$ is necessary.

So I established the following equalities:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}}-\frac{x}{n+3}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4}}-\frac{x}{n+2}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}}{n^2+2n+5}-\frac{x}{n+3}}{\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4}}{n^2+4}-\frac{x}{n+2}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+5}-\frac{x}{n+3}}{\frac{n}{n^2+4}-\frac{x}{n+2}}$$

From here on, when I do the reductions, it seems to me that the limit is $1$ regardless of what the value of $x$ is. In that case, the sum isn't convergent.

Have I made a mistake, should I change my approach? Feeling somewhat lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When the limit is $1$, the test is inconclusive.  So, if you're getting $1$, this means that you can't use this test.  It doesn't mean that the sum is or isn't convergent.

Comment: Here's perhaps a better approach: for almost all values of $x$ you'll have $a_n$ (roughly) proportional to $\frac1n$; specifically, you'll be able to find some constant $C$ with $|a_n|\gt \frac Cn$ for all (sufficiently large) $n$. There's only one value of $x$ for which this isn't true. Find out approximately what size the term $a_n$ is for that $x$, and then use the $p$-test to handle both cases.

Comment: Your claim about a "necessary condition" is wrong. First of all, the correct expression there should be $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$. Second, this condition is sufficient, but not necessary. Counterexample: $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitvely, as $n$ gets large $\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+4}}$ is close to $\frac 1n$ and we know the sum of that diverges logarithmically.  We need to cancel the $\frac 1n$ term to make the sum converge.  As $\frac x{n+2}$ becomes $\frac xn$ for large $n$, we need $x=1$

We can expand both of the terms in a series near $\infty$.  [We have](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20$1%2Fsqrt(n%5E2%2B4)%20near%20infinity) $\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+4}}\approx \frac 1n -\frac 2{n^3}+\frac 6{n^5}+\ldots$ and $\frac x{n+2} \approx \frac xn -\frac {2x}{n^2}+\frac {4x}{n^3}
 +\ldots $  To get the terms in $n^{-1}$ to cancel we need $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your last equality is somewhat fishy. You are replacing $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+5}}$ with $\dfrac{n+1}{n^2+2n+5}$ directly in the numerator. While that is true asymptotically, you can't just do it when computing a bigger limit which involves more expressions than those two.

Better approach would be consider the partial sum $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4}}-\dfrac{x}{n+2})$ and get an asymptotic using various known results.